# JQuery JSON - Using variables

Tags: jquery, json

OK let's say I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="images">
Hello<br />
</div>
<script>
$.getJSON("main.txt",
  function(data) {
    var getTitle = title;    
    $.each(data.getTitle, function(i,getTitle){
       $("#images").append(getTitle);
    });
  });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

it doesn't work because of `var getTitle = title`. I know that. But if I take out the `var` and replace `getTitle` with `title` which is INSIDE the JSON file.. it WILL work. But I don't want to edit three pieces of `title` for each code so I just make a variable so I can edit all three at once... but it doesn't work...

Comment: I dont't understand what do you try to do. what is `title` - is it defined somewhere?

Comment: @Guard, Its a typo, he meant  var getTitle = "title";   The point being if the JSON changes, that he only has to change the value of getTitle.. I agree that it wasn't massively clear though.

Comment: `data.title` is a string. Why are you using `$.each()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just make a variable so I can edit all three at once

That doesn't make any sense. The name of the variable doesn't matter at all. For what you're doing, this works just as well:

```
$.getJSON('main.txt', function(data) {
    $.each(data.title, function(i, anyVariableNameILikeGoesHere) {
        $('#images').append(anyVariableNameILikeGoesHere);
    });
});
```

However, jQuery actually provides a more concise way of writing this:

```
$.getJSON('main.txt', function(data) {
    $.each(data.title, function() {
        $('#images').append(this);
    });
});
```

---

Aside from that though, why are you iterating over `data.title`? Looking at your json, it's a single string! This is a much better way to write it:

```
$.getJSON('main.txt', function(data) {
    $('#images').append(data.title);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of accessing the object as data.getTitle, try using [].

```
var getTitle = "title";
$.each(data[getTitle], function(........)
```

This would solve the problem.